# RAILS rails assets:precompile fails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have RAILS 6.0.3 running, so I use the webpacker.

When I try to compile the assets with rails **assets:precompile** in RAILS deveopment mode it runs very well, but when I try to run it in RAILS production mode I got the error message:

> Compilation failed:
> CssSyntaxError: /data/rails-base-dir/jquery-ui.css:1:1: Unknown word

But the file /data/rails-base-dir/jquery-ui.css does not exist !
So there is something wrong with paths/locations...

I have no approach how to fix it.

For installation jquery-ui : I have followed this guide : [gist.github.com/.../#jquery-jquery-ui](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/2612fa987b9f9ed7cb53a88fcba247b3#jquery-jquery-ui)

Comment: I use the jquery-ui gem for this reason. Try adding it via the gem and removing the library you added yourself since it works out the compatibility issues:   https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails

Comment: I tried to replace the yarn package by this gem package. 
I did as requested -----
1) gem 'jquery-ui-rails'   ------ 
2) In   app/javascript/packs/application.js  ------
require('jquery-ui'); ------
But the jquery-ui function I want to use does not work any more. -----
JS Error : .autocomplete is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After somes days to try and work - found a solution.
There is one gap that I have in my knowledge. How the webpacker works and how to configure. With RAILS 6 there are a lot of configuration files now switched to javascript style. So Javascript moves to a more important position.

I want to share one really good page that brings more light in more dark webpacker knowledge: [Page from Ross Kaffenberger](https://rossta.net/)

This page was useful: [How to debug webpack on Rails](https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-debug-webpack-on-rails.html)

I found that `./bin/webpack --debug` was compiling the javascript code. And then doing `rails assets:precompile` or a `rails webpacker:compile` works without failure.

But I did not found out the reason of the initial failure :

> Compilation failed: CssSyntaxError:
> /data/rails-base-dir/jquery-ui.css:1:1: Unknown word